# Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have installed bs4 using

`pip install bs4`

I run `pip list` and `beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0) bs4 (0.0.1)` both appear.

but when I run python from the command line I get 
`import bs4
ImportError: No module named bs4`

I'm new to python so any help would be great.

Comment: Make sure you are in the same venv. Could be you have installed bs4 into a venv and then run Python in global, or vice versa.

Comment: How can I figure that out?

Comment: Open the python interpreter/repl in the same terminal session where you can see that bs4 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im guessing that you are trying to import like this:
`import bs4`

try this line instead

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`